# Packaging android library and includes others libraries in generated aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to build an android library including others libraries. I have 2 workspaces like this :

```
/workspace1
  /libA
  /myLib

/workspace2
  /myApp
```

The android library myLib depends on libA.

The android application myApp depends on myLib (and use classes from libA).

I would like to generate AAR for myLib to my local maven repository (it's OK). But the generated AAR does not contain classes and resources from libA.

Please see the build.gradle under workspace1 :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'
    }
}

def groupVal = "com.mycompany.android"
def versionVal = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

def compileSdkVersionVal = 19
def buildToolsVersionVal = "19.0.3"
def minSdkVersionVal = 10
def targetSdkVersionVal = 19

allprojects {
    group = groupVal
    version = versionVal

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

}

project(':libA') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersionVal
        buildToolsVersion buildToolsVersionVal

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion minSdkVersionVal
            targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVal
            versionCode 1
            versionName versionVal
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

    }

}


project(':myLib') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'
    apply plugin: 'android-maven'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion compileSdkVersionVal
        buildToolsVersion buildToolsVersionVal

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion minSdkVersionVal
            targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVal
            versionCode 1
            versionName versionVal
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        compile project(':libA') {
            export = true
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Many thanks,

Leo

Answer (score 1):

You should depend on libA.jar instead of libA.aar in your myLib project. Then, assuming you are building the apk through myApp/pom.xml, you should depend on libA.aar in that pom file.

- If libA.jar does not exists, you have to manually create and install it into your maven repository (e.g., .m2) using 'maven install ...' command to be able to depend on it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want myLib to contain the classes and resources of it's dependencies, you need to create a so called 'fatJar' from it. This means that the all, (or selected) dependencies will be packaged into single archive alongside the code itself.

Beware, that this way the consumer of the library will lose the ability to dynamically adjust dependency versions, because they'll be stuck with what you packaged into your library.